# Calendar, mouseover on day >> show what's in the row that contains that date

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following simple list in a sheet named "Pipeline":

[image]

Whenever a date is entered in column E, those dates get formatted in another sheet named "Calendar" (same document), where I have a calendar that looks like this:

[image]

This is the conditional formatting formula: `=match(B1,indirect("Pipeline!E:E"),0)`

To this point, all good.

Now, when I am in "Calendar", I would like to output the topic from sheet "Pipeline" respective to the date I mouseover, or I select.

For example, if I now select cell V16 in "Calendar", which corresponds to date "18 Jun", I need "Retargeting for Ho" (value of cell A10 in sheet "Pipeline") to be output somewhere.

I don't quite care how. It may be a cell in the the Calendar sheet, or mouseover. Really, the output format is not that necessary.

Hope someone can help.
Thanks in advance.
A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Approach

This behavior is achievable through an event programming technique. In Google Sheets you can trigger functions based on these events:

- Document open
- Document edit
- Document selection

For this purpose you can use the `onSelectionChange(e)` function. A handler for the `Document selection` event.

To handle these events you will need an Apps Script project. You can easily bound one to your Spreadsheet going to `Tools>Script Editor`.

#### Output representation

I think that on Google Sheets you can benefit of the Note UI representation to show the wanted information based on the selected cell content.

#### Code:

Here is an example on how to handle the selection event to append a Note UI element to the selected cell:

```js
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  let date = e.range.getValue().toString(); // I will explicitly cast the date object to string to ensure the comparison will work
  let range = e.range; // This will return a range of exactly one cell: The selected one
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let pipeline = ss.getSheetByName('Pipeline');
  let pipelineRows = pipeline.getDataRange().getValues(); // I will load all the Pipline table in a multidimensional array to get the title information
  let title = pipelineRows.filter(row => row[5].toString() == date).map(row => row[1]); // I will filter the Pipeline Rows by date and extract the title
  range.setNote(title); // Finally I will append the extracted title to a note in the selected cell.
}
```

### Reference

[Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)

[Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

[SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet)

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your feedback. Unfortunately returns an error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined (line 2, file "Code")"

Comment: Hello, how are you running the function?

Comment: Forget my previous comment, it works like a charm, I just had to change the row index, being 0-indexed, from 5 and 1 to 4 and 0.
Thank you so much for your help!